# if two array has identical values in same format irrespective of key without using any loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
array1 = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>1 )
array2 = (g=>1, d=>2, f=>3, e=>1 )
```

I cannot use `===` operator as keys are different. The above two arrays has same value format, want to display yes if they have, I can always run a loop but want to avoid that part.

Comment: when you say format what do you mean? Are you looking to compare values? We need to see some of the code you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for `array_values()`:

```
<?php
$array1 = ['a'=>1 ,'b'=>2, 'c'=>3, 'd'=> 1];
$array2 = ['g'=>1 ,'d'=>2, 'f'=>3, 'e'=> 1];

var_dump(array_values($array1)===array_values($array2)); // bool(true)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary standardize the key first using array_values() function.

```
$tmp1 = array_values(array1);
$tmp2 = array_values(array2);

if($tmp1 === $tmp2) echo 'yes';
```